# Code Igniter $config['master_dim'] not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Code Igniter to upload Images. in my farm i have option for user to set Image width and height.

If user set both height and with then image should be resize to specified width and height.

If user set only width the images should resize to that with if user set height the image resize to that height if user did't set with and height image will not resize

I have following code but its not working when user is setting either width or hight.

```
$data_file = $this->upload->data();
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = FPATH.'uploads/'.$data_file['file_name'];
$config['create_thumb'] = false;

 if($img_width>0 && $img_height>0){
 $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
 $config['width']    = $img_width;
 $config['height']  = $img_height;

 }elseif($img_width>0 && $img_height<=0){
 $config['width']    = $img_width;
 $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;    
 $config['master_dim'] = 'width';    

 }elseif($img_width<=0 && $img_height>0){
  $config['height'] = $img_height; 
  $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
  $config['master_dim'] = 'height';        
  }

 $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

 $this->image_lib->resize();
```

This is working fine when i specify width and height but if i specify only width or height it resize it to that width or height but with ratio.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you should provide a default width or height in case width or height is not mentioned because an image is comprised of both width and height!

something like this would work i guess -

```
 $data_file = $this->upload->data();
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = FPATH.'uploads/'.$data_file['file_name'];
$config['create_thumb'] = false;
$default_width=100;
$default_height=100;

// elseif conditions

elseif(!(isset($img_width)) && !(isset($img_height))){
  $config['height'] = $default_height; 
  $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
  $config['master_dim'] = 'height';        
  }


  }

 $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

 $this->image_lib->resize();
```